# Python cp437 encoding not found

Tags: python, encoding

It seems some packages messed up libs of my Python 3.9 setup.

It started with using zipfile package (more specifically pyzipper version of it).
After I used it few times I first got a strange bug:

```
aise CDefError("invalid constant %r" % (s,))
cffi.CDefError: :10: invalid constant '32'
```

described here: https://github.com/danifus/pyzipper/issues/33
Did reinstall pyzipper, pycryptodome (cause potentially conflicting with pyzipper's pycryptodomeX), cffi ... Didn't help.
Managed to avoid this error putting pyzipper import first. But then I got new error that's there even with the orig zipfile lib.

Python39\lib\zipfile.py", line 1364, in _RealGetContents
filename = filename.decode('cp437')
LookupError: unknown encoding: cp437

It seems python does not see the cp437.py encoding file I have in my Python39/Libs/encodings

What is strange is I'm not using any special chars in the zip file name or in the zipped file, I have plain "asci_char.zip" and inside there is "a.txt" file.

I'd like to understand :

- why this can happen libs can get messed up
- how to fix it (make python force see the cp437 codec...)

Tried to debug and google, seen some other stackoverflow posts but didn't found the answere.

Comment: Tried to import encodings before zipfile, didnt help, still python cannot see cp437.

Comment: Decided to move to Python 3.11, reinstalled the packages and can move on with work ...

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve]. In particular, share as little code as possible that still produces the same problem *and* full traceback…

Comment: I've shared as much info as possible. Also checked google before and it looks like this problem is very rare == hard to reproduce. Most likely some lib or app messed Python lib/config for some reason. Reinstalling whole Python + packages helped. If you don't think this post helps anyone I do not mind deleting it.